# Manga ripper with performance and blocking issues

Tags: c#

I just thought about creating a C# program to download all chapters of a manga given an URL. HTML parsing is done with `HtmlAgilityPack`.

Issues I have yet to work out are the blocking of the whole program, the rather slow performance of `GetPagesLink()` as it calls `LoadHtmlCode()` which uses `WebClient` a lot (one Webclient object for every page inside a chapter multiplied by number of chapters) and the continuous increase of used memory. At first it starts with ~14 mb but increases infinitely. Besides that, everything works.

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Treasure;

namespace MangaRipper
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        #region Properties

        private Uri _Uri;

        public Uri Uri
        {
            get { return _Uri; }
            set { _Uri = value; }
        }

        private List<Tuple<string, string, string>> _Chapters = new List<Tuple<string, string, string>>();

        public List<Tuple<string, string, string>> Chapters
        {
            get { return _Chapters; }
            set { _Chapters = value; }
        }

        private string _MangaName;

        public string MangaName
        {
            get { return _MangaName; }
            set { _MangaName = value; }
        }

        #endregion Properties

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private string LoadHtmlCode(string url)
        {
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    // Avoid too many connection requests at once to prevent website from blocking us
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
                    client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                    client.Proxy = null;
                    return client.DownloadString(url);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Logger.Log(ex.Message);
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }

        private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Multiple mangas are delimited by a semicolon..
            string t = txtURL.Text;
            string[] split = t.Split(';');

            foreach (var item in split)
            {
                CreateDirectory(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(item));
                MangaName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(item);
                Uri tempUri = new Uri(item);
                Uri = tempUri;
                try
                {
                    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                    {
                        string htmlCode = LoadHtmlCode(Uri.AbsoluteUri);
                        LoadAllChapters(htmlCode);
                        Download();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Logger.Log(ex.Message);
                    Logger.Log(ex.StackTrace);
                    Logger.Log(ex.InnerException.ToString());
                }
            }
        }

        private void CreateDirectory(string dirName)
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(dirName))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dirName);
            }
        }

        private void Download()
        {
            foreach (var chapter in Chapters)
            {
                string bla = chapter.Item2;
                string chapterName = bla.Replace("?", "%3F").Replace(":", "%3A");
                // Skip this chapter if it already exists based on chapter name
                // TODO: Find better way to determine this. Incomplete downloads to a folder would be marked as completed...
                if (Directory.Exists(string.Format("{0}/{1} - {2}", MangaName, chapter.Item3, chapterName)))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(string.Format("{0}/{1} - {2}", MangaName, chapter.Item3, chapterName));
                }
                List<Tuple<string, int>> temp = new List<Tuple<string, int>>();
                foreach (var item in GetPagesLink(chapter.Item1))
                {
                    temp.Add(new Tuple<string, int>(GetImageLink(item.Item1), item.Item2));
                }

                foreach (var img in temp)
                {
                    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
                    webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
                    webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(img.Item1), string.Format("{0}/{1} - {2}/{3}.jpg", MangaName, chapter.Item3, chapterName, img.Item2)); // TODO: Find image type and replace hardcoded jpg
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(150);
                }
                temp.Clear();
                txtDebug.AppendText("Finished chapter " + chapter.Item3 + "\r\n");
            }
            Chapters.Clear();
        }

        private void ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Return a list containing tuples with the direct url to all pages of a chapter
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="url"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private List<Tuple<string, int>> GetPagesLink(string url)
        {
            List<Tuple<string, int>> pages = new List<Tuple<string, int>>();
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            htmlDoc.LoadHtml(LoadHtmlCode(url));
            int counterPage = 1;

            foreach (HtmlNode node in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//select[@id='pageMenu']//option"))
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Value=" + node.Attributes["value"].Value);
                //Console.WriteLine("InnerText=" + node.InnerText);

                pages.Add(new Tuple<string, int>("http://" + Uri.Host + node.Attributes["value"].Value, counterPage));
                counterPage++;
            }
            return pages;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Extract direct download link of an image by given url
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="url"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private string GetImageLink(string url)
        {
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            htmlDoc.LoadHtml(LoadHtmlCode(url));

            return htmlDoc.GetElementbyId("img").GetAttributeValue("src", "not found");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Load all chapter urls into Chapters property
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="htmlCode"></param>
        private void LoadAllChapters(string htmlCode)
        {
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            htmlDoc.LoadHtml(htmlCode);

            var chapterLink = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(@"//div[@id='chapterlist']//a/@href");
            var chapterName = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(@"//div[@id='chapterlist']//a/@href/following-sibling::text()[1]").Reverse().ToList();
            for (int i = 0; i < chapterLink.Count; i++)
            {
                var link = "http://" + Uri.Host + chapterLink[i].GetAttributeValue("href", "not found");
                var name = chapterName[i].OuterHtml.Replace(" : ", "");
                var number = chapterLink[i].InnerText;
                Chapters.Add(new Tuple<string, string, string>(link, name, number));

                checkedListBox1.Items.Add(link);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For logging I wrote a logger in a separate class and namespace:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Treasure
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Logger class. Creates per-day logs, saved into "Log" directory
    /// </summary>
    public class Logger
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Logs the specified log message
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="LogMsg">The message to be logged.</param>
        /// <param name="args">Arguments like {1}</param>
        public static void Log(string LogMsg, params object[] args)
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\Log"))
            {
                try
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\Log");
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\Log\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy") + ".txt", true))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + " " + string.Format(LogMsg, args));
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
#if DEBUG
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message + e.StackTrace);
#endif

#if RELEASE
                    MessageBox.Show("Could not create Log directory.", "Error");
                    Log(e.Message);
#endif
                }
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    // Creates per-day log file with current date as file name
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\Log\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy") + ".txt", true))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + " " + string.Format(LogMsg, args));
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message + e.StackTrace);
                    Log(e.Message + "\n" + e.StackTrace);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Suggestions unrelated to performance: do a stylecop pass; remove unused usings; use implicit property backing variables (i.e. `public Uri Uri { get; set; }`)

Comment: And don't roll your own logging class. There are plenty of good ones from NuGet.

Comment: Your `Log` method is a `StackOverflowException` waiting to happen.  Don't reinvent the wheel anyway.  I'd grab NLog from NuGet.

Comment: `LoadHtmlCode(string url)` should be made to accept an actual `Uri` instance and not a string (avoid stringly-typed variables).

Comment: @Zer0 I though about using a already existing framework for logging but all the overhead and initial config looks like overkill to me. Of course I will consider it for a large scale project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A large part of the problem is doing `Thread.Sleep` on the UI thread.  You could mark the methods `async` and use `await Task.Delay` instead if you want a non-blocking sleep.

```
public async Task MethodThatRunsOnUIThread()
{
    //Do stuff
    //Wait
    await Task.Delay(150);
    //Do more stuff
}
```

But if I designed this I would do the entire workload asynchronously.  That would involve a little bit more work.  But you could start with something simple like this:

1. Disable part of the UI.
2. `await` a `Task.Run` on the entire workload.
3. Re-enable part of the UI to allow a second run.

Something like this:

```
private async void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnLoad.Enabled = false;
    string url = txtURL.Text;
    await Task.Run(() => DoLoad(url));
    btnLoad.Enabled = true;
}
```

Then while performing work asynchronously you can marshal back to the UI thread to update status using `BeginInvoke`.

I'm not sure why you're creating a million `WebClient` instances.  Sometimes not even using them:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    string htmlCode = LoadHtmlCode(Uri.AbsoluteUri);
    LoadAllChapters(htmlCode);
    Download();
}
```

There's nothing stopping you from sharing a `WebClient` instance.